# Node.js get data from github api

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api, rate-limiting

Ok here's the deal, I need to get data from Github API say gists from multiple repositories. I don't want to save any data, should I implement streams or is there some other way? in either cases what are the modules I can use to achieve this? There is a per hour rate limit for the calls to the API.

Also how should the rate limiting be handled, I have had a look at [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) of lodash but didn't get a fair idea how can that be useful.

Comment: If you want to limit lookups, you generally use a DB to cache the data in. As for making requests to Github, that should be easy, and there are several modules available for making requests, for instance [Request](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: @adeneo I am making use of the gihub module in npm. The thing is that the page limit for single call for the API is 100 so I have to make multiple calls to get all the data. I wanted to know if there is some module using which I can do this in a sophisticated manner?